# Adding and Retrieving multiple values with Firebase under "User"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crud

Im uploading my data like this:

[image]

By using these function:

```
extension Database {

func createPurchase (purchaseID : String, quantity: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()){

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let userPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("purchases").child(uid) //taken off auto ID
    let values = ["purchase" : purchaseID, "quantity" : quantity ] as [String: Any]

                    userPostRef.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to save purchase to database", err)
                completion(err)
                return
            }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }

}
```

.

In Viewcontroller 1:

```
func callID (){
    let itemCount = CartController.shared.items.count

    for i in 0...itemCount-1 {

        let quantity = CartController.shared.items[i].quantity
        let quantity1 = String(quantity)
        let item = CartController.shared.items[i].product.id

        Database.database().createPurchase(purchaseID: item, quantity: quantity1 ) { (err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("error uploading purchase to Firebase ")
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

callID uses createPurchase to take the sku number of each product and its quantity and uploads to firebase.
However, it overrides what was previously uploaded. So when I load more than 1 product. It only leaves the last products sku and quantity.
For this example, I started with 3 product, but only 1 (the last one) got uploaded.
How can I upload all the data. i.e stop this overide?

Here is how Im retrieving it:

```
extension Database {
    func fetchPurchase(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Purchase) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("purchases").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            let purchase = Purchase(uid: uid, dictionary: userDictionary)
            completion(purchase)
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch purchase from database:", err)
        }
    }
}
```

.

In viewcontroller 2:

```
struct Purchase {

    let uid: String
    let purchases: String
    let quantities: String


    init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.purchases = dictionary["purchase"] as? String ?? ""
        self.quantities = dictionary["quantity"] as? String ?? ""

    }
}

var myPurchases: [Purchase] = []

private func fetchPurchaseForCurrentUser() {
    guard let currentLoggedInUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    Database.database().fetchPurchase(withUID: currentLoggedInUserId, completion: { (purchases) in
        self.myPurchases.append(purchases)
        print("myPurchases", self.myPurchases)
    })
}
```

This is the printout I get:

`myPurchases [myShop.Purchase(uid: "Tgb9MyxTfdTRd9tQhInsjNRXoPL2", purchases: "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0Lzk4OTUzMDk2OTk=", quantities: "2")]`

This only shows the one product, however Im needing to have multiple products.

Please Help!

EDIT:

This is a screenshot of when I use ChildByAutoId(). 
I get all products (2 in this case).
But I am unable to retrieve the information from the snapshot and set to my text fields?

[image]

Comment: You need all purchases or do you want to filter it with some value?

Comment: Because Database.database().reference().child("purchases").child(uid) this will return you only one value. And if you can more purchases in the screenshot that will be helpful.

Comment: I can only store one value of purchases, but I want to store more. If I use ChildAutoId, then I can store them all. However I can retrieve them all?

Comment: If you want to get all values use "Database.database().reference().child("purchases")" with single value observer

Comment: Adding "child(uid)" will give you a matching result only

Comment: You should store uid inside the bean, and generate autoId for key value. After that you will be able to get multiple values for a single user via using: Database.database().reference().child("purchases").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in })

Comment: Ive put a screen shot in the edit. 
I can get all the products into firebase with ChildByAutoId, but I cant retrieve them from this form,

Comment: Database.database().reference().child("purchases").child(uid) in this what is the value of uid?

Comment: uid = "Tgb9MyxTfdTRd9tQhInsjNRXoPL2"

Comment: In that case Database.database().reference().child("purchases").child(uid) this will give you both records

Comment: It only gives me 1 product. See the data at the top of question.

Comment: Print userDictionary in func fetchPurchase

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: this is the print out `["-LzjaFBiAmrj4m3ZS8m4": {
    purchase = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0Lzk4OTUzMDk2OTk=";
    quantity = 2;
}, "-LzjaFBgD3ATl7e8uR2-": {
    purchase = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0Lzk4OTUzMjEyODM=";
    quantity = 1;
}]` I just cant call the purchase data into its own array now

Comment: So you are getting both elements

Comment: Please check the answer below for data parsing in case of multiple beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare an array from multiple records, sample code:

```
var myPurchases: [Purchase] = []
for (key, value) in userDictionary {
    guard let dic = value as? [String: Any] else {
         continue
    }

    let purchaseModel = Purchase(uid: key, dictionary: dic)
    myPurchases.append(purchaseModel)
}
```

Comment: cant recognise json.dictionaryObject

Comment: Do I put this in the func fetchPurchaseForCurrentUser()? I dont have userDictionary in the view controller Im trying to get the data to

Comment: You will get userDictionary in fetchPurchaseForCurrentUser via let userDictionary  = purchases[uid] and then you can use the above code to add values to your purchase model.